# Can I change my Facebook Page settings so that sharing Page posts will automatically include the original post (i.e., original text)?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I run a Facebook Page, and when people have been sharing our posts that include external links, the original text disappears.

I know that there is a workaround for people who are sharing the content, but I would like to make my Page so that sharing a post from my page includes the original post by default. That way, people won't have to do it themselves.

Here's the original post:

[image]

Here's what it looks like when someone shares it. You can see that all the original text from the Page has been removed:

[image]